# The UI Is Unresponsive When Loading Large Document in UI Thread, Even with BackgroundWorker Implemented

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I asked a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085067/how-to-make-sure-ui-is-responsive-using-backgroundworker); thanks to everyone who provided suggestion! However, it seems that my problem is bigger than the one described above, so I am posting a new question.

The issue is that I need to keep my UI responsive when I am loading a large document using a third party control called `document`. The `document` is a class embedded in a third party control, there is no way for me to new it, and it doesn't have `Invoke` function.

I am trying to use `Backgroundworker` for this. The code I try is of this form:

```
public class MyForm: Form
{
private delegate bool OpenFile(string filePath);
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{



    OpenFile oF = new OpenFile(document.Open);
    var openFile = this.Invoke(oF, MyFileName);  

    e.Result = openFile;
}
}
```

Now, in the UI thread, where `document` belongs, when it is doing the `Open` operation, a dialog box is supposed to come up and updating itself and the main thread is supposed to remain responsive ( i.e., I can still drag and drop the form anyway I like). This is what I was trying to accomplish.

The problem is that the above code will make both of my threads ( the main UI thread and the dialog box thread) hang during the time of loading. *My question is,is there anyway to fix this issue?*

**P/S: I have tried `var openFile = Invoke(oF, MyFileName)` and `var openFile = BeginInvoke(oF, MyFileName)` and `var openFile = OtherControl.Invoke(oF, MyFileName)`, all didn't help.**

Comment: It sounds like you have a poorly designed control (in the sense that it was not designed to handle a large document).  Have you try contacting the vendor to ask for a fix or workaround?

Comment: @jdigital, not sure whether that's possible or not. The third party vendor is notoriously hard to deal with. But, this there other way?

Comment: @Ngu, Please read, and think carefully about the information in this useful CodeProject article:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/begininvoke.aspx
If you want to write multi-threaded Win Forms applications there is no alternative but to understand how these methods work.

Comment: @Ash, the problem is that the control is performing the processing and the OP can't find a way to make the control perform the work in the background.

Comment: @jdigital, I'm well aware of that. You're missing the point though.  The control is owned by the main GUI thread but Ngu wants it to do it's processing on a background thread.  I'm trying clarify why this is not possible in Win Forms.

Comment: @Ash, if you had stated this up front ("not possible in Win Forms") then we wouldn't be having this discussion ;-)  I do hope this clarification helps the OP.

Comment: Does the control in question provide any kind of incremental loading?  For example, can you load part of a document and then append additional data?

Comment: @jdigital, no. The control doesn't provide any facility of that kind.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  Short of reverse engineering and hacking the control (as mentioned by Yoooder below), it looks like you're stuck.  Time to think about writing your own replacement for the control.

Answer (score 2):

Your included example doesn't show quite enough to clearly identify the problem.  My assumption is that your class doesn't contain an explicit `Invoke()` method, so your example is calling `Form.Invoke()`.  If that's the case then you're misunderstanding the purpose of that method.

`Form.Invoke()` ensures that the included delegate is executed *on the UI thread*.  Therefore your background thread isn't actually doing the work, instead your background thread is returning to your UI thread prior to executing the delegate... hence the unresponsive UI.

You might be the victim of an unfortunate ambiguity... both `System.Delegate` and `System.Windows.Forms.Form` & `Control` contain methods named `Invoke()` and `BeginInvoke()` but serve different purposes.  Unfortunately this is where your sample is a little incomplete.  Is `OpenFile` a delegate?  Does your class contain an explicit `Invoke()` method?

---

Update: After some discussion in the comments the feasible options were whittled down to either:

- Trying to preload the data to a temporary in-memory location on a background thread, then loading the 3rd Party UI control from that location versus from the filesystem/network
- Using .NET Reflector to examine the internal/non-public API of the control and attempt to use Reflection to override the current behavior by calling non-public methods or setting fields/properties

Comment: Yes, you are right, `document` doesn't contain an `Invoke()` method. So how would you fix the problem?

Comment: `OpenFile` is a my own delegate, where as the class ( `document`) doesn't contain an explicit 'Invoke' ( its not a proper control, just a class)

Comment: Also, the `Invoke` is an invoke on the form; I've updated the question

Comment: If oF is a delegate that takes a string, you can just call oF(someString) -- that runs the oF delegate with the argument you pass.  (You can also call Delegate.DynamicInvoke, you'd normally only do this if you didn't have a defined delegate type like your OpenFile delegate type.)

Comment: @itowlson, I understand. But this point is trivial and doesn't help in solving the problem at hand.

Comment: It's not trivial, it's fundamental to the problem you're seeing.  Your UI is blocking because, as Yoooder has explained, `this.Invoke(oF, MyFileName)` is running in the UI thread.  (Because `this` is the form instance.)  That's what Invoke does: it makes the delegate run on the invokee's thread.  So now the UI thread is blocked opening the file, and the BackgroundWorker thread is blocked waiting for Invoke to return.  By contrast, `oF(MyFileName)` will run in the BackgroundWorker thread, and will not block the UI.  Give it a quick try!

Comment: like itowlson has repeated... calling `Invoke()` ***is explicitly telling your delegate to execute on the UI thread!***.  Replace `Invoke(oF, myFileName)` with `oF(myFileName)` and that should ensure your intensive operation is executed on the background thread.

Comment: I'm tipping if he runs oF(myFilename) directly in the background worker thread, he will get the usual cross thread GUI exception.  So, @NGu Soon Hui, once again, if at all possible use this.BeginInvoke() (where this is the Form). It is **guaranteed** by the framework that Control.BeginInvoke will not block (wait).  Double-check that you are calling BeginInvoke on the Form instance.

Comment: @Ash, unfortunately, I've tried `this.BeginInvoke`, and yet the threads still hang.

Comment: @Yooder, replacing `Invoke(oF, myFileName)` with `oF(myFileName)` will generate a cross thread exception at the end.

Comment: @Ngu, if 'this' is a Form instance it cannot block/lock because it is simply calling the WinAPI PostMessage() to place a message on the GUI threads message queue.  PostMessage does not care if the GUI thread is locked or not.

Comment: @Ngu if `oF(myFileName)` is generating a cross-thread exception then it is because it is updating the UI which necessitates that it execute on the UI thread.  Therefore you have two options:  (1) Remove the `BackgroundWorker` implementation--as it buys you absolutely nothing and in fact slows the process down further, or (2) refactor the method being called by `oF()` to seperate out the data-intensive operations from the UI updates--then background the data-load and only return to the UI to update the screen when complete.

Comment: @Yooder, as mentioned in my question, the data-intensive operation can only be done by a property inside a control on the main UI thread. So how can I separate that out?

Comment: I see that you're depending on a third-party control; what options do you have for opening the file?  Are you currently loading it across the network?  Could you use a background-thread to load the file to a `MemoryStream` and open it from in-memory rather than from disk or from the network?  Have you used .NET Reflector to review the behaviors of the control?  Provided you can comprehend their control, and that it is moderately well-designed interally, then you may be able use Reflection to access non-public methods/properties and coerce the behavior

Comment: @Yooder, maybe that's the only way I can take. In the mean time, can you edit your answer to reflect this knowledge so that I can accept your answer? Also remember to put put a comment to this question after you have done it so that I will be notified.

Answer (score 0):

Older question, but no answer marked as being right so I asume the problem wasn't solved by the current answers.

I had a problem with the same symptoms. Using a background worker thread the UI bacame non-responisve.

I basically followed the follwoing tutorials:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hybbz6ke.aspx
http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/06/understanding-c-using-backgrou.html

Reported some progress and got stuck with a non responsive UI. Turned out I was giving to much to fast progress and just updating the progress made my UI responsive. Changing the number of progress updates to one for every thousend items solved my problem.

Hope this helps.